# How to create a Jquery Plugin with Plugin Methods and Maintaining Chainability?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create a Jquery plugin   that maintains chainability and has public methods  as specified in Jquery [Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) . The complexity is that it is trying  to maintain certain vars that I want the public methods to use.

This is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/badmash69/9cqcj/2/

```
javascript code :

(function($){

  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) {
      this.options = options;
    }
  , add_that: function (elem) {

      $(this).append(elem);
      return (this);
    }
  , show_parent: function(){
      // this is a simple test to see if the plugin vars are accessible
      alert("parent id=" + $(this).parentId)
    }              
  , add_this: function (elem) {
      return methods.add_that.apply(this,elem);
    }
  };

  $.fn.test = function (method) { 
        var args = method;
        var argss = Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1);      


      return this.each(function(){

          var $this = $(this);
          if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.test' );
    }          


          var element = $(this);
          var parentId= element.parent().attr("id")

      });       


  };

})(jQuery);

$('#test').test('add_this',$('<div>Hello World d</div>'));

$('#test').test('show_parent');
​
```

Html Code

```
<div id="holder">
<div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

I cant figure out what I am doping wrong here .
How can I make it work ?  I would deeply appreciate any help  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9cqcj/11/

As they suggest, to keep data you should better use `.data`:

```
      return this.each(function(){          
          var $this = $(this);
          $this.data("parentId",$this.parent().attr("id"));
....
```

(assuming that you need parentId of each element in set)

Also, you have a problem with calling your methods:

```
 return this.each(function(){

          var $this = $(this);
          if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
```

Last line, `arguments` - arguments of function passed to `.each` is used. In order to get original arguments save them into variable before calling a method:

```
$.fn.test = function (method) { 
        var args = arguments;      
      return this.each(function(){          
          var $this = $(this);
          $this.data("parentId",$this.parent().attr("id"));
          if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( args , 1 ));
```

See arguments replaced with args in last line.

Also, when you are using `.apply`, second parameter should be an array:

```
return methods.add_that.apply(this, [elem]);
```

In case like this:

```
return methods.add_that.apply(this, elem);
```

You can get unexpected problems. For instance, try to replace `elem` with simple string `"test"` and see what you will get in console. Or if  you will pass jQuery object, you will get DOM object in called method

Answer (score 1):

the way that I do this is using the $.data, you can have specific object local vars, "public"/"private" methods, etc. here goes an small example in how I will do it

```
(function($){
      var myTestMethods = function() {
          // local variables
          var last_added;

          // local "private" methods 
          var init=function(options) {
              this.options = options;
              last_added = null;
              return this;
          };

          var add_that=function(elem) {
              last_added = elem;
              this.append(elem);
              return this;
          };

          var show_parent=function() {
              alert("parent id=" + this.parent().attr('id'));
          }

          return { // this are your obj "public" methods
                 // notice we are not listing add_that method, therefore this method will be a "private" method
            init : init,
            show_parent: show_parent, // you can publish a private method
            get_last_added: function(){
              return last_added; // you can access local variables
            }, 
            add_this: function (elem) {
              return add_that.apply(this, elem);  // you can also run local methods
            }
          }
      };

      $.fn.test = function (method) {
          var obj_data = this.data('myTestData');
        if (typeof(obj_data) != "undefined") {
          if ( obj_data[method] ) {
            return obj_data[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
          }else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.test' );
          }
        } else {
          if (typeof(method) === 'object' || ! method) {
            obj_data = myTestMethods();
            this.data('myTestData', obj_data);
            return obj_data.init.apply(this, arguments);
          }
        }
      };

    })(jQuery);

    $('#test').test(); //init

    $('#test').test('add_this',$('<div>Hello World d</div>'));
    $('#test').test('show_parent');
```

this code has small tests so there may be small bugs, but this will show you the basic idea in how to do what you want.